# Navbar Brand toggler opens the Navbar contents aligned right then jumps to centred?

Tags: html, css, navbar, react-bootstrap

I am using a React Bootstrap Navbar brand on my website so on smaller viewports such as smartphones it uses a toggle to open up the contents of the navbar.

I have an issue whereby when you initially click on this toggler it plays the short transition of opening it but does so to the right side of the screen rather than central which is where it ends up. This makes it look like the contents are jumping from right to left. (Hopefully, the screenshots shows this better than I have explained it)...

[image]
[image]

Below is the code for my Navbar component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import {
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="md" className="custom-nav-bg fixed-top">
        <Link className="navbar-brand" href="#home" to="/">

            <img className="custom-nav-logo"
            src="logohero.png"
            alt="StatHero Logo"
            width="105px"
            height="50px" />

        </Link>

        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" className="navbar-dark custom-button align-items-center" />

        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav" className="justify-content-end navbar-align">
          <Nav className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#about" to="/about">
            ABOUT
            </Link>

            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#stats" to="/stats">
            STATS
            </Link>

            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#faqs" to="/faq">
            FAQS
            </Link>

            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#contact" to="/contact">
            CONTACT
            </Link>

            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#signup" to="/signup">
              <Button className="custom-nav-button">SIGN UP</Button>
            </Link>

            <Link className="custom-nav-text" href="#login" to="/login">
            LOGIN
            </Link>

          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    )
  }
}
export default NavBar;
```

The only custom classes I have used are:

```
.custom-button {
  align-self: flex-end;

  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 175px;

  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: #132A42;
}

.navbar-align {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: I've noticed with the react-bootstrap componenet such as the toggle they act strange when I assign them another class, perhaps the style you're giving it is clashing with the standard built it.   try removing your classes that you've given and see if it has a similar behavior.  (I have personally moved away from using their togggle and built my own)

Comment: I think you're right it does seem to be a clash between my styling and the react-bootstrap class. I just can't seem to din the class it's clashing with... something to do with the transition of it opening up...?